# Redirect subdomain with www. to without www

Tags: apache

I know there are a lot of such questions, but I could not find a suitable answer.

I am on a shared shell with web hosting.

I have a subdomain- "xyz.abc.com".
The problem is that when I type an extra "www." preceding it i.e. "www.xyz.abc.com", it redirects to the root website which hosts the shell i.e. "www.abc.com" instead of opening "xyz.abc.com".

I had contacted the admin. and he said that he cannot change the redirection settings as he will have to rewrite 2000 lines of APACHE server code.

I tried changing the .htaccess file in my public_html directory i.e "/home/usr/public_html/.htaccess" to include this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This does not help.

I tried adding a .htaccess at "/home/usr/.htaccess". This too does not work.

I cannot add any files at "/home".

Is there any easy way for the admin. to change this redirection problem.

```
Most people tend to add a "www." before any web address.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default virtual host (in this case, apparently abc.com's main site) will be the one that answers for domains the server gets requests for but doesn't know about.  In your case, the server knows that `xyz.abc.com` goes to your site.  However, it's never heard of `www.xyz.abc.com`.  And since it hasn't, the request goes to the default site, which probably does its own 301 to bounce to the site it expects to be (which is apparently `www.abc.com`).

In order to fix this, assuming the host isn't willing to modify their own web site for you (and of course, assuming that the domain name `www.xyz.abc.com` points to the same server as `xyz.abc.com`), someone needs to add `www.xyz.abc.com` or `*.xyz.abc.com` to the list of domain aliases for your site.  If the server was set up decently for hosting, that's *one line* (`ServerAlias *.xyz.abc.com`) in the configuration for that site.  2000 lines amounts to an Apache config for an entire small-to-medium-capacity web server, including a dozen or so individual name-based virtual hosts.  If the admin was not exaggerating, then they're basically telling you that that server is not set up for real, business-grade web hosting -- they're probably doing a cheesy mass-vhost thing that can't be tailored for individual users.

If you can't get the admin to fix up the server aliases for you, one alternative would be to acquire yourself a domain from a registrar that offers "URL forwarding". When set up properly, that'd point your domain at a site that simply redirects to `xyz.abc.com`. That's kinda ugly, but it works as long as all the links within your site go to `xyz.abc.com` (some URL forwarders might not pay attention to the resource part of the URL, and might redirect everything to `/`). And it doesn't require the admin to do anything.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Is there any other option. I wanted to know of all the options before informing the admin. to try them out. It's a very good FREE shell host, so I can't ask much. The admin's a nice guy.

Comment: @dams: Updated to include a solution that doesn't require the admin to do anything.  :)